# How to get the request URL details using rails

Tags: http, ruby-on-rails-4, mobile, request

How to Get the below information from the user request URL using rails.

connection type (mobile/wifi) - device brand (applle , htc) - device models (ipad, iphone ) - language(englishm japanese) , operating system (ios , windows, blackberry), web borwser (chrome, firefox)

Example: when the users enters the url lik "http://example.com/samples"
i need to track the details of the request comes to the rails server.

Is the any gems are rails methods available ? Please help me out this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Detect Mobile Browsers by http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/
>
> Detect OS

```
def get_operating_system
  if request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/mac/i)
    "Mac"
  elsif request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/windows/i)
    "Windows"
  elsif request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/linux/i)
    "Linux"
  elsif request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].downcase.match(/unix/i)
    "Unix"
  else
    "Unknown"
  end
end
```

> When someone visits your website, Ahoy creates a visit with lots of
>   useful information.
>
> ```
> traffic source - referrer, referring domain, landing page, search keyword
> location - country, region, and city
> technology - browser, OS, and device type
> utm parameters - source, medium, term, content, campaign
> ```

Reference link : http://ankane.github.io/ahoy/

> Mobvious detects whether your app / website is being accessed by a
>   phone, or by a tablet, or by a personal computer.

reference link : https://github.com/jistr/mobvious

> Do some browser detection with Ruby. Includes ActionController
>   integration.

https://github.com/fnando/browser

Comment: thanks for the reply. so how can i get the other information ?

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, i hope this will help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to make some analytics.
It's already implemented with some gems.

I can advise you : [ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy)

- traffic source - referrer, referring domain, landing page, search keyword
- location - country, region, and city
- technology - browser, OS, and device type
  utm
- parameters - source, medium, term, content, campaign

If you want you can keep trying to advance it by looking at [Mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com).
It provide you a dashboard with some analytics of your application.

Comment: how to get the connection type details, like wifi / mobile brandband / lan connection also the devise type like sony , htc, apple, samsung

Comment: Ahoy give you many details about the device :

- the os (android/ios)

- the version of the os (in the user agent)

- the browser (mobile safari/chrome...)

For the connection type I don't have any idea, sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser) gem  to extract information about the user's browser. It is very intuitive and easy to use.

```
<% if browser.windows? %>
  <p class="info">You are running on Windows!</p>
<% end %>
```